Is Time a Parameter in Relativistic Lagrangian Mechanics?
In a previous homework on the analysis of some relativistic Lagrangian, I got a comment that saying the Lagrangian was cyclic in time (or that time is a cyclic variable) because
$
\partial_t \mathcal{L}=0
$
was false because time is a parameter in Lagrangian mechanics. While I agree for non-relativistic mechanics, but I thought the whole point of special relativity was that we promote time to be a coordinate, and that's why we then define our action as an integral over infitesimal spacetime intervals rather than time.
Anyone have an idea of where my thinking is going wrong? A classmate said if we are thinking about the trajectory of a relativistic particle, we still think of time as the parameter when we pull it out of the spacetime interval, $ds$. This makes sense somewhat, but I still feel like $ds$ is the fundamental parameter here.

In the SR action, with $c=1$, $S = - m \int d \tau \sqrt{(\frac{dt}{d\tau})^2 - (\frac{d\vec{r}}{d \tau})^2} = \int d \tau L(\tau;t,x,y,z;\dot{t},\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})$, we see $t,x,y,z$ are cyclic variables, and proper time is a parameter. If we choose the gauge $\tau = t$, we get $S = -  m \int d t \sqrt{1 - (\frac{d\vec{r}}{d t})^2} = \int L(t;x,y,z;\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})$, now time $t$ is the parameter & is not a cyclic variable, i.e. the SR action is invariant under worldline reparametrizations $\tau \to \tau'(\tau)$, and a choice is a 'gauge choice' with different properties.

Ah, I see, thank you for the clarification!
